# Saturn Aura 07 help

Tags: electrical, starter, saturn, aura

Had starter replaced,went out to drive the vehicle and about 30 minutes after i left the radio went off and all the dash warning lights came on then the car stopped and will not start. This morning i went out to the car and turned the key to the run position radio played for about 30 seconds. dashlights worked for about a minute and 30 seconds then the only light that were on was the security light and check engine. Any ideas what the problem could be

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though the battery is dead. Two things to check.

First, check to see that the power wire going from the battery to the alternator is in place. When changing out the starter, the technician my have inadvertently disconnected it or broke it lose without replacing it. If this has happened, the battery would not have been recharged after startup, which means the battery would be drained down to the point of not being able to keep the engine running. Restoring the wire and connection, along with charging the battery would solve your issue. NOTE: This would be the same result as if the alternator had died and is no longer charging the battery. I wouldn't rule out the alternator, but I think this scenario is more likely.

Second, your battery may just have died. Check the voltage at the battery. If the battery is at 10vdc or lower, you can try and charge it. If charging it works (brings it up to a 12+vdc steady state), you'll need to check the first situation above. IF it doesn't help, you can take it somewhere and have it load tested. Anywhere which sells batteries should be able to test it for you.